# Pandas - Extract dataframe rows with a column matching a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

To return a dataframe `df` rows corresponding to column `A` with values 1, we can specify

```
df.loc[(df['A']==1)]
```

How to get `df` rows corresponding to column `A` but matching a list of numbers say 1,2,3 something like

```
df.loc[(df['A']==[1,2,3])]
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['A'].isin([1,2,3])]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks. Post it as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: That's alright. Glad to help.